# PHP ob_start: callback a static method with $this

Tags: php, output-buffering, ob-start

With PHP's ob_start($callback), you can pass a static method as a callback like this:

```
class TemplateRenderer {
  function myCallback($bufferContents) {
    return 'Foobar instead of the buffer';
  }
}

ob_start(array('TemplateRenderer', 'myCallback'));
```

Or you can refer to an object like this:

```
$myTemplateRenderer = new TemplateRenderer();
ob_start(array($myTemplateRenderer, 'myCallback'));
```

Both of these work, but I'd like to know if I can start the output buffer from within a class method, and refer to the callback using $this

```
class TemplateRenderer {
  function myCallback($bufferContents) {
    return 'Foobar instead of the buffer';
  }

  function init() {
    // --- this doesn't work ----
    ob_start(array($this, 'myCallback'));
    // --- this doesn't work either ----
    ob_start(array('this', 'myCallback'));
  }
}

TemplateRenderer::init();
```

If it's even possible, what's the syntax for referring to a "callable" from within its own class?

Comment: What should `$this` be when you use `TemplateRenderer::init()` to call the function? `$this` is only set when you use `$object->method()` syntax.

Answer (score 3):

I would follow Barmar's suggestion, but if you for whatever reason don't want to make instantiation, you can try this solution:

```
class TemplateRenderer {
  static function myCallback($bufferContents) {
    return 'Foobar instead of the buffer';
  }

  function init() {
    ob_start(array('self', 'myCallback'));
  }
}

TemplateRenderer::init();
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the answer I was looking for: 'self' where I was trying 'this' and $this. I'm actually getting an error now on the dev server where I'm trying it: "Invalid callback self::myCallback, cannot access self:: when no class scope is active" but I think I'm on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `init()` using an object so that `$this` will be set.

```
$myTemplateRenderer = new TemplateRenderer();
$myTemplateRenderer->init();
```

Comment: Sorry, I think my problem got lost in translation when I was trying to simplify my code sample for this thread, and mention the two use cases (static method and object method). Either way, I tried it again this morning and the object style did work with $this